# c# compare string list to regex list

Tags: c#, regex

I have two lists; one containing the *strings* I want to test and one containing *Regular Expressions as strings*.
I want it to test each item in the StringList to be tested for `regex.IsMatch` with each item in the RegexList.

What's the easiest way of achieving this?
Do I have to extract the Strings containing the Regexes first or is it possible without having to do that?

Comment: Do you want to check if the string matches any regex? If so, can you join the expressions together and then match against that? Something like `var regex = new Regex(regexlist.Join("|")); foreach(strings..s) { regex.IsMatch(s); }`.

Comment: The Regexes are already in the RegexList in a string format. And I want to check each String in the StringList for each Regex in the RegexList.

Comment: But that's two simple for loops then, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a foreach statement.

```
foreach(string item in StringList)
{
  foreach(var reg in regexList)
  {
    if(reg.IsMatch(item))
     ///Do something 
  }
}
```

Comment: wouldn't it be `if(Regex.IsMatch(item, reg))`?

Comment: @user123456 yes that would be the correct way.
But: Creating regexes is extremely expensive. .Net interns the 15 last used regexes - so if the List of regexes is longer than 15, the loop is horribly expensive because new regexes have to be created constantly. In that case, it would be better to create regexes once and loop over this list of RegExes.
I profiled an application yesterday that did not intern a regex properly - changing it reduced processing time by 30% (one line of code!)